# My servicestack cached service includes extra slashes in the response

Tags: c#-4.0, redis, servicestack

I have created a cached webservice using ServiceStack.

```
public class ContentSearchService : ServiceBase<ContentSearch>
{
    public ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }

    protected override object Run(ContentSearch request)
    {


        var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request2";
        return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(this.CacheClient, cacheKey, () =>
        {
            //Delegate is executed if item doesn't exist in cache


            //Any response DTO returned here will be cached automatically
            return new ContentSearchResponse()
            {
                Contents = new List<ContentData>()
                {
                    new ContentData()
                    {
                         FileName = "testfile.jpg"
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    }
}
```

This is then run using:

```
IRestClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://internal");

ContentSearch search = new ContentSearch();

ContentSearchResponse response = client.Put<ContentSearchResponse>("/json/syncreply/ContentSearch", search);
```

The first response is returned as expected and converted into the response object. The second, which is cached is returned with extra slashes and as a result can't be serialized.

First response:

```
{"Contents":[{"FileName":"testfile.jpg","Company":0,"Version":0}]}
```

Second response:

```
{\"Contents\":[{\"FileName\":\"testfile.jpg\",\"Company\":0,\"Version\":0}]}
```

I'm using Redis as the cache.

I've had a look at the redis server they are stored with the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was related to the client using a different version of the ServiceStack assemblies.  I updated both the server and client to the lastest and everything worked as expected.